# Select nav list item with Jquery (with URL loading)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this nav menu:

```
    <ul>
      <li class="click-li" id="tray-active"><a href="/">Home</a></li> <!-- Active page -->
      <li class="click-li"><a href="/news">News</a></li>
      <li class="click-li"><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
      <li class="click-li"><a href="/sales">General Sales T and C</a></li>
      <li class="click-li"><a href="/jobs">Job Opportunities</a></li>
      <li class="click-li"><a href="/inquire">Inquiry</a></li>
    </ul>
```

When the anchor is clicked it will re-load the page (since my site is based on a CMS). So I am guessing this is the reason why this code would not work:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("document ready");
        $("#tray li").removeAttr("id"); 

        $('.click-li').live('vclick', function() {
          var subMenuItem = $(this).text();
          alert('Sub Menu Item: '+subMenuItem);
        });
  });
```

My main goal is to set the clicked `tray li` `id` attribute to `"tray-active"` so the CSS for active `nav` will be applied.

Update:

Ok so this worked:

```
        $('.click-li').on('click', function() {
          var subMenuItem = $(this).text();
          alert('Sub Menu Item: '+subMenuItem);
        });
```

Still having problem since when the page reloads, after clicking on of the nav menu, the selected `li` gets its "active" css style, how do I iterate over the other `.click-li` except for the one pointed by `$(this)` so I can remove their id's?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()`

Comment: I dont see an id of "tray" where you're calling the remoteAttr function?

Comment: why are you using `'vclick'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking after

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("document ready");
    $('.click-li').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".click-li").removeAttr("id"); 
        var subMenuItem = $(this).text();
        alert('Sub Menu Item: '+subMenuItem);
        $(this).attr("id", "tray-active");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XYJaf/6/

Comment: oops, it prevented the redirect when the nav menu item is clicked

Comment: get ride of event.preventDefault(); it will redirect.

Comment: If you want to redirect then you might need to work differently because when you come back to this page after redirecting it will not persist which li has id and which does not. Javascript is done in client side and when you redirect it will come from server side.

Comment: yah, this is why i'm really having some problems making this work

Comment: perhaps I can check the browser url? or is there any other elegant solution with this?

Comment: Yes the ideal way is to send parameter with browser URL as get request. Use that GET request value and assign it into some javascript variable and iterate through list and assign this desired Id into that li. Or use PHP to iterate through ur li and assign Id to desire dom.

Comment: Use this to find index 
$('.click-li').click(function(event){ $('.click-li').index($(this)); })
and pass this value as request parameter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25974/discussion-between-prp-and-xybrek)

Answer (score 0):

Use event.preventDefault: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
This will keep the page from re-loading when you click on the anchor tag. Also, consider using .on as .live is deprecated.

```
$('ul').on('click', '.click-li', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var subMenuItem = $(this).text();
    alert('Sub Menu Item: '+subMenuItem);
});
```